# how to synchronise removal of b2bodies when firing in game

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my game i have some monsters and my hero. when i fire some bullets i remove bodies on collision either with monster or ground body, and also added a timer event to remove the bullet as

```
-(void) removeProjectile:(CCPhysicsSprite*)projectile{
         dispatch_time_t removeProjectile = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1* NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(removeProjectile, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        int i;

        for(i=0;i<deadBodyCount;i++)
        {
            if(deadBodies[i] == projectile.b2Body)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==deadBodyCount)
        {
            deadBodies[deadBodyCount]=projectile.b2Body;
            deadBodyCount++;
        }
    });
}
```

but what happens my code crashes, don't know. please help me. If you have any approach to do this.
i am removing deadbodies in

```
-(void)removeDeadBodies{
for (int i=0; i<deadBodyCount; i++) {
    if(deadBodies[i]){
        if([self getPSTag:deadBodies[i]]==3){
            CCPhysicsSprite *temp=(CCPhysicsSprite *)deadBodies[i]->GetUserData();
            NSLog(@"%@",temp);
            [[self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode]removeChild:temp cleanup:YES];
        }
        else if([self getPSTag:deadBodies[i]]==2){
            for (int j=0; j<monsterCount; j++) {
                if (monsters[j].b2Body==deadBodies[i]) {
                    [[self getChildByTag:kTagParentNode]removeChild:monsters[j] cleanup:YES];
                    monsters[j]=NULL;
                }
            }
        }
        _world->DestroyBody(deadBodies[i]);
        deadBodies[i]=NULL;}
    }
   deadBodyCount=0;
  }

 -(int)getPSTag:(b2Body *)body{ //physics sprite tag value from a b2Body
CCPhysicsSprite *sprite=(CCPhysicsSprite*)body->GetUserData();
//Here is the error------------------------------------
if(sprite)
    return (int)sprite.tag;
else
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my begin contact method

```
-(void)beginContact:(b2Contact *)contact{
b2Body *bodyA=contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
b2Body *bodyB=contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
int collideCheck=[self checkForCollisionGroups:bodyA And:bodyB];
if(!collideCheck)
    return;
switch (collideCheck) {
    case 1:
        for (int i=0; i<monsterCount; i++) {
            if(monsters[i].isVisible){
                //Checking if Projectile hitting the monster
                //bodyA is monster and bodyB is projectile
                if([self getPSTag:bodyA]==2&&[self getPSTag:bodyB]==3){
                    [monsters[i] monsterHit];
                    [self doExplosionAtPoint:monsters[i].position];

                    deadBodies[deadBodyCount++]=monsters[i].b2Body;

                    CCPhysicsSprite *x=(CCPhysicsSprite *)bodyB->GetUserData();
                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        if(deadBodies[i]==x.b2Body)
                            return;
                    }
                    deadBodies[deadBodyCount++]=x.b2Body;

                    [self.top updateScore:100];
                }//bodyA is Projectile and bodyB is Monster
                else if([self getPSTag:bodyA]==3&&[self getPSTag:bodyB]==2){//if one of the         body is projectile
                    [monsters[i] monsterHit];
                    [self doExplosionAtPoint:monsters[i].position];

                    CCPhysicsSprite *x=(CCPhysicsSprite *)bodyA->GetUserData();
                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        if(deadBodies[i]==x.b2Body)
                            return;
                    }
                    deadBodies[deadBodyCount++]=x.b2Body;

                    deadBodies[deadBodyCount++]=monsters[i].b2Body;

                    [self.top updateScore:100];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (jumping==YES) {
            jumping=NO;
        }
        break;
    case 3: //bullet hitting with any object
        if([self getPSTag:bodyA]==3){//if one of the body is projectile
            CCPhysicsSprite *x=(CCPhysicsSprite *)bodyA->GetUserData();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                if(deadBodies[i]==x.b2Body)
                    return;
            }
            deadBodies[deadBodyCount++]=x.b2Body;
        }
        else if ([self getPSTag:bodyB]==3){
            CCPhysicsSprite *x=(CCPhysicsSprite *)bodyB->GetUserData();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                if(deadBodies[i]==x.b2Body)
                    return;
            }
            deadBodies[deadBodyCount++]=x.b2Body;
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        for (int i=0; i<monsterCount; i++) {
            if(monsters[i].isVisible){
                if( (bodyA==monsters[i].b2Body&&bodyB==_heroBody)||(bodyA==_heroBody&&bodyB==monsters[i].b2Body)) {
                    _heroBody->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(-3*hero.scaleX, 5));
                    lifeCount=[_top updateHealthMeterWithDamage:10];
                    NSLog(@"collide");
                    moving=false;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    /*case 6:if([self getPSTag:bodyA]==33){
        movingTile.position=((CCSprite*)bodyA->GetUserData()).position;
            }
        else
             movingTile.position=((CCSprite*)bodyB->GetUserData()).position;*/
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: with what you increament the array deadBodies? is it bullets or monsters or both? where is your code crashes?

Comment: what line is the crash? what's the error message? Add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: error is "bad access exception "

Comment: please do suggest what i should do to get rid of this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code. I dont understand the use of removeProjectile: CCPhysicsSprite*)projectile{} method while you indirectly actually adding the projectiles to the deadBodies[] in the beginContact(). So i guess here you have two pointers pointing to same body. And when you run the removeDeadBodies() for loop, it actually first deletes the body and then in next iteration when again it gets the dangling pointer with no body then it crashes.

I commented the line [self removeProjectile:projectile]; in the createProjectileAt() method. And now everything is working fine.

I know it might be late to implement but a suggestion, to have better hold on your b2Bodies and safe deletion from world, you can take a struct datatype with data members as a Sprite and a BOOL variable say isDelete. And use this struct as the userdata of the body. So now you can just set this bool variable to YES inside beginContact() call back. And in you update: tick method after the world->step is over just iterate through the world of bodies and check the BOOL var that can be deleted. HEre you can safely delete the bodies. No need to maintain an array of deadBodies etc. Hence there will not be any synchronization issue.

Comment: i am doing deadbodycount=0 because all dead bodies have been removed in removeDeadBodies method

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try that once. And dont set deadbodycount=0 inside the for loop. Because setting it to zero inside the for loop will cause it the loop run only once or never. This may happen when deadBodies[i] is already set to NULL earlier.

Comment: i am not setting deadbodycount=0 inside the for loop, perhaps outside of it. check it. I appreciate your answer but when i fire at large amount, then same exception is thrown at the same point.

Comment: Did you try the edited answer getPSTag() above? And i am sure you have deadbodycount=0 after the  if(deadBodies[i]){} block which is inside the for loop.

Comment: yes i have edited getPSTag(), and remove the line deadBodyCount=0;

Comment: whats the result? is the edited method still crashing?

Comment: tell me your mail id i will send you the code, then you can better look at it, mr. krish

Comment: Soory. Earlier i overlooked the } at the deadBodies[i]=NULL; line. Hence was telling you not to set zero to the variable.if you wish you can send it to cubedevs@gmail.com

Comment: i have sent you the code, please have a look at it.

Comment: i am calling the remove projectile method because my projectiles (bullets) can either be removed on collision or after an interval if they don't collied to any body.

Comment: as you have suggested to make structure, i think that can't solve the actual problem and also i have a monster class to create special type of physics bodies, so they can't be included with that structure.